# Converting structures to scalar

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
Stats(1).Area = 12
Stats(2).Area = 27...
```

etc.

When I do the following in the command window:

```
vec = [Stats.Area];
```

It works fine and I get a vector with all the values of the `Area` field for the size of the structure `Stats`.

But the same line of code from within a function returns:

```
Dot name reference on non-scalar structure.
```

Any idea why this works from the command window but not from within a function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you pass the structure to the function?

Comment: Can you show the code of the function and the code calling the function?

Comment: Can you use `dbstop if error` and see whether the struct in fact does not only contain scalars?

Comment: Works fine on Matlab 2010b. Show us the code...